# StringBuffer и StringBuilder в языке Java

Tags: java

В чем разница между классами `StringBuffer` и `StringBuilder` в языке Java?

Answer (score 1):

По своей сути StringBuilder такой же по функционалу, как и StringBuffer. Просто StringBuffer является синхронизированным и поэтому более безопасен при использовании в многопоточной среде. От этого StringBuffer работает медленнее, чем StringBuilder

Comment: не думаю, что стоит на такие элементарные вопросы отвечать

Comment: `StringBuffer` не является безопасным для использования в многопоточной среде, так как синхронизация отдельного вызова `append` бессмысленна и либо требует дополнительной синхронизации в вызывающем коде, либо приводит к нарушению инвариантов.

Comment: @Санаев Однозначно имеет. Но конкретно на этот вопрос уже ответили

Comment: @AntonShchyrov в сети сейчас столько информации. Нужно уметь гуглить

Comment: @Санаев Я по себе знаю. Я гуглю элементарные вопросы, меня гугл выкидывает на SO (правда на enSO), где я и нахожу искомый ответ. А если не отвечать на такие вопросы, то и ответов не будет